# How to pass this variable on other .php file with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass the id in posts.php  with ajax and here in href i want to put "#".

When this link gets clicked, It goes to that link. But I dont want  to go that link and at a same time i need to pass the id in posts.php.

How can I do this?

```
<li><a href="posts.php?id=<?=$post_id?>" >post</a></li>
```

Comment: Use javascript method to do this. `<a href="javascript:gotoAction($post_id)">` and write a js function `gotoAction()` and inside the function call ajax to your desired url.

Comment: Inline javascript: is not a great idea

Comment: can you please give me a example of this ?

Comment: Can you explain why inline `javascript:` is not a good idea? @mplungjan

Comment: It is accepted standard to separate view and logic. And with jQuery it is so simple to attach event handlers to the code. Also if JS is turned off, you will get a 404 or similar.

Comment: But if js is turned off, your `jquery` also be stuck here. [apart from `separate view and logic`]:) @mplungjan

Comment: Sure, but then you can have href="turnyourjson.html" instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<li><button type="button" id="pass-data" data-postid="<?= $post_id; ?>">Click me</button></li>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("#pass-data").click(function(){ // on button click
    var dataid = $(this).attr("data-postid"); // get post id

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "posts.php", // page to post data to
        data: { id: dataid }, // the post_id (you can access it with $_POST["id"])
        success: function(){ // if successful
            alert("Success!"); // alert "success!"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why a button He does not have a button

Comment: @mplungjan saves having to add `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: No it doesn't because your button is not type=button and some browsers will submit the page to itself with the default type=submit

Comment: It will only ever default to that when it is within a `form`. So, unless that is the case, it will be fine.

Comment: Nope. Some browsers will submit to the page itself regardless of form or not.

Answer (score 1):

Like this - note the preventDefault that stops the link:

```
<li><a class="postLink" href="posts.php?id=<?=$post_id?>" >post</a></li>

$(function() {
  $(".postLink").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    $.post(this.href,function(data) {
      console.log("Posted the link, returned:",data);
    });
  });
});
```

OR

```
<li><a class="postLink" href="#" data-id="<?=$post_id?>">post</a></li>

$(function() {
  $(".postLink").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
    $.post("posts.php",{"id":$(this).data("id")},function(data) {
      console.log("Posted the link, returned:",data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I recommend the 2nd answer, with `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: @GrégoireFruleux then feel free to vote up :) - the void(0) is handled by the preventDefault

Comment: Woops I thought I've done it :P I know, it's more kind of a preference to use void(0) for links with specific behaviours ;)

Comment: Thanks, They look so ugly when moused over. ¨